# In place matrix multiplication numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of point arrays, and as I iterate through it I want to do in-place matrix multiplication i.e. I want the result stored in the same matrix.

The code is essentially:

```
for p in p_list:
    # R is a 3x3 matrix
    p[:,:] = np.matmul(R,p)
```

This code shows no error but the result is incorrect, as if the multiplication is performed in the arrays and substituted as calculated, so it creates a wrong output matrix. Removing [:,:] give a correct multiplication.

1) Why does this happen exactly?
2) The main reason I used [:,:] is to make sure the result is stored back in the list p_list. Is there a correct way to do that (without using an intermediate variable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1:

If I understand correctly, you could use `enumerate` to go through the indices and values of your `p_list`, and assign the result of your `matmul` to given index.

For example, if your data look like:

```
>>> R
array([[0.00169934, 0.66346914, 0.07109019],
       [0.28354322, 0.45933175, 0.55396787],
       [0.22061139, 0.18207232, 0.51669746]])
>>> p_list
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

Then you can do:

```
for i,p in enumerate(p_list):
    # R is a 3x3 matrix
    p_list[i] = np.matmul(R,p)
```

And your resulting `p_list`:

```
>>> p_list
array([[1.54190819, 2.86411033, 2.13484839],
       [3.7506842 , 6.75463886, 4.89299187]])
```

**[EDIT]** based on @domochevski's comment, this method could more easily be done with a list comprehension:

```
np.array([np.matmul(R,p) for p in p_list])
```

## Method 2:

Alternatively, you could use [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html), and apply a custom function that returns `matmul(R,x)` to each row:

```
def my_matmul(x):
    return np.matmul(R,x)


p_list = np.apply_along_axis(my_matmul, 1, p_list)
```

Which returns the same:

```
>>> p_list
array([[1.54190819, 2.86411033, 2.13484839],
       [3.7506842 , 6.75463886, 4.89299187]])
```

Comment: For your first method rather than using a `for` loop, why not go for an enumeration?

Comment: Damn me for posting a comment without thinking first. I meant list comprehension. Sorry for that.

Comment: @domochevski, thanks for the comment, I overlooked that possibility, but it is indeed easier, see edits above

Comment: Two of your three methods are not in-place in the correct meaning of the word. If you assume the author's intent is simply to maintain the symbol name, then the best answer would be `p = np.matmul(R,p)`, which two of your answers are just a round-about means to achieve. Your first `enumerate` method is correct, but @hpaulj's answer is faster (profiled with `timeit`).

Answer (score 4):

`matmul` accepts an out parameter

If `p_list` is an `ndarray`, with shape `N, 3`, then you can achieve the entire multiplication in one `matmul`:

```py
np.matmul(p_list, R.T, out=p_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

With @sacul's example:

```
In [59]: R.shape
Out[59]: (3, 3)
In [60]: p_list.shape
Out[60]: (2, 3)

In [58]: np.array([np.matmul(R,p) for p in p_list])
Out[58]: 
array([[1.54190819, 2.86411033, 2.13484841],
       [3.7506842 , 6.75463885, 4.89299192]])
```

`einsum` generates the same (new) array without external loop:

```
In [61]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',R,p_list)
Out[61]: 
array([[1.54190819, 2.86411033, 2.13484841],
       [3.7506842 , 6.75463885, 4.89299192]])
```

And like `ufunc`, it accepts an `out` parameter:

```
In [63]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',R,p_list, out=p_list)
Out[63]: 
array([[1.54190819, 2.86411033, 2.13484841],
       [3.7506842 , 6.75463885, 4.89299192]])
In [64]: p_list
Out[64]: 
array([[1.54190819, 2.86411033, 2.13484841],
       [3.7506842 , 6.75463885, 4.89299192]])
```

I'm sure it uses an intermediate buffer, but should be faster than iterating row by row.  Using the `out` is a bit slower than simply letting it return a new array.

With a tweak in dimensions, `matmul` can perform the whole calc in one call (the key is to pair the last dim of `R` with the second to the last of `p_list` (modified)).

```
In [84]: (R@p_list[:,:,None])[:,:,0]
Out[84]: 
array([[1.54190819, 2.86411033, 2.13484841],
       [3.7506842 , 6.75463885, 4.89299192]])
```